# PyQt - QGridLayout set first Row stylesheet

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I am generating a Gridlayout and adding Widgets as follows:

```
    elements = QGroupBox()
    self.grid = QGridLayout(elements)

    #Arrange Row Elements
    self.grid.addWidget(subjectName, 0, 0)
    self.grid.addWidget(statusName, 0, 1)
```

I would like to have a **background-color** for the first row (not the Widgets inside the row), to indicate the header of the Grid.

**Result i  want:**
[image]

Comment: This looks like you are trying to do what a `QTableWidget` is better suited for, or a `QTableView`.  If you are setting the background of widgets in a QGridLayout, it depends on the widget... you could do it with `setStyleSheet` for each of those widgets.

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24233-QTableWidget-change-header-background-color-QHeaderView

Comment: Is it possible to add widgets to the QTableView?

Comment: Yes.  But it does require using the [Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) methods for the most part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the QObjects properties to distinguish between the cells when setting a stylesheet.

It is possible to use e.g.

```
setProperty( "coloredcell", true )
```

on the widget added to the QGridLayout in combination with

```
parentWidget.setStyleSheet("*[coloredcell=\"true\"] {background-color:rgb(" + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + "," + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + "," + QString::number((rand() % 255)) + ");}");
```

where the parentWidget is the Widget containing the QGridLayout.

To have the backgroundcolor in the complete range of a single cell, you have to add an intermediate QWidget to the QGridLayout, set the property, add a intermediate Layout to the intermediate QWidget and into this, you can add your widget you want to see in the table.

Without the intermediate widget, if you set the "coloredcell" property to the actual widget itself (in my example, the QPushButton), only the backgroundcolor of this widget will be changed, not the color of the whole QGridLayout cell. That's why we need it.

Example code (untested) :

```
widget = QWidget()
gridLayout = QGridLayout(widget)
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        intermediateWidget = QWidget(widget)
        intermediateWidget.setProperty("coloredcell", true)
        intermediateLayout = QGridLayout( intermediateWidget )
        button = QPushButton( QString( "Row %1 Col %2" ).arg(i).arg(j) )
        gridLayout.addWidget(intermediateWidget, i, j)

widget.setStyleSheet("*[coloredcell=\"true\"] {background-color:rgb(255,0,0);}")
widget.show()
```

Comment: how is this covered in pyqt?

Comment: This is how it works in c++, I tested it myself. I "translated" it to python for the lack I have no installed pyqt on the machine I'm using at the moment. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: this will set the background for the widget but not the cell right?

Comment: Yes, but the widget can fill the whole cell.

Comment: Yes, but not all widgets are expanding fully into cells, so i've created a QFrame Object and added the QLabel to that Object.

Comment: Would you edit my post so it satifies your question if someone else reads it?